# Edge won't connect to internet, Skype for business won't screen-share, Windows Store won't update apps after Windows 10 version 1809 installed

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, skype-for-business, windows-10-v1809

I ran into a problem after upgrading Windows 10 October 2018 to version 1809. After the Windows update I noticed the following problems with Microsoft applications:

- Microsoft Edge could no longer connect to the internet even though Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 still could.
- Skype for Business (formerly Lync) no longer allowed me to share my screen or view another person's shared screen.
- The Windows Store could not connect to the internet to update apps.
- The Microsoft Feedback portal could no longer connect to the internet.

How can I resolve these network issues that seemed to cooincide with an upgrade to Win10 ver 1809?

Answer (score 3):

After digging a bit, it looks like the issue is related to IPv6 being disabled in the network connection settings.

Go to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center`

[image: network settings]

Click on the 'Ethernet' link, or other network connection you are currently using. This should bring up the following window.

[image: Network status window]

Next click on the 'Properties' button. Scroll down and make sure that IPv6 (circled below) is checked.

[image]

Once checked, close all the network windows and try to connect again with one of the Microsoft products that were previously not working. These apps should now work again.

**reference:**
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/microsoft-edge-and-other-microsoft-store-apps/75ac54dd-cd56-41d8-a205-7948e54f39be